# How do I prove that Intermediate Value Theorem applies when limits as $f(x)$ approaches infinity exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Be $ {\lim_{x\to \infty}}f(x) = a$ and $ {\lim_{x\to -\infty}}f(x) = b$
with $a<b$

And $f(x)$ is continous in $\mathbb R$.
Then for any $a < c<b$ exists $x$ with $f(x)=c$
as per definition exists for every $\epsilon>0$ $M$ and $|M-f(x)|<\epsilon$

My approach would be:
for any $\epsilon>0$ we have an interval $[M,N]$ for which the IVT applies.

Would that be to naive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not naïve at all.

Since $a<c<b$, if you take $\varepsilon=\min\left\{\frac{c-a}2,\frac{b-c}2\right\}$, then:

- $\varepsilon>0$
- $a+\varepsilon<c<b-\varepsilon$.

So, there is a $M>0$ such that $x\geqslant M\implies\bigl|f(x)-b\bigr|>\varepsilon\implies f(x)>b-\varepsilon$. And there is a $N<0$ such that $x\leqslant N\implies\bigl|f(x)-a\bigr|>\varepsilon\implies f(x)>a+\varepsilon$. Now, you apply the intermediate value theorem to $f$ and to the interval $[N,M]$.

Comment: should't it be $f(x) < b - \epsilon$ , so that you have $ c < f(x) < b$

Comment: @inevitable No. From my computations I was able to deduce that $f(M)>b-\varepsilon>c$ and that $f(N)<a+\varepsilon<c$. Since $f(N)<c<f(M)$, I can apply the intermediate values theorem to the interval $[N,M]$ and to the function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is the correct approach, there exists $u,v$ such that $a<F(u)<c<F(v) <b$ apply IVT on $[u,v]$.